# Qt - approach to coding GUI

Tags: qt, dialog, window

I have a Qt progam that I've made using Qt Creator. I made a .ui dialog (mainwindow.ui), and in the ui editor add the controls and slots. These end up creating methods in mainwindow.cpp eg.

```
void MainWindow::on_btnRunJohn_clicked()
```

In these methods, I'm accessing the controls directly to update them eg.

```
ui->txtConfigFileName->setText("Some text to put in the text box");
```

I know there are numerous ways to manage window dialogs in Qt (eg. QML, subclassing), but am wondering whether this approach is suboptimal, or limits things in some way. Is this a reasonable way to code in Qt, or is there a better approach to managing dialogs? I'm happy defining the controls up front ie. I don't need to add/delete controls at runtime.

Comment: surely it's reasonable...

Comment: Thanks CapelliC - I just hadn't seen the approach directly in some of the examples, and wondered whether there was something wrong with it. Will keep coding as is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually if you want to change the behavior of the Ui, this is the way you have to go.

I suggest that you can use **Multiple Inheritance**, just like this:

```
class A : public QDialog, public Ui::A
{
    // class methods and members
}
```

This will help you to use the Ui widgets easly.

Comment: By the way, the TextFinder example in Qt Creator gives a simple demonstration of this approach. It subclasses QWidget and contains a slot attached to a button that updates the ui.